# Groovy/Grails - Json web service, map received with extra properties

Tags: json, web-services, grails, groovy

I'm busy working on a function that sends a map (and other irrelevant values) through a json web service but the problem is that on the receiving side it sees it as `JSONObject` (using the getClass() method) and coz of this it adds extra properties to the object thus causing the service to return an error. So on the sending side the map println's like this:

```
[21:{adultValue=1, kidValue=0}, 11:{adultValue=0, kidValue=4}]
```

But on the receiving side it println's like this:

```
[11:[metaPropertyValues:[[name:adultValue, modifiers:1, type:java.lang.Object], [name:kidValue, modifiers:1, type:java.lang.Object]], properties:[kidValue:4, adultValue:0]], 21:[metaPropertyValues:[[name:adultValue, modifiers:1, type:java.lang.Object], [name:kidValue, modifiers:1, type:java.lang.Object]], properties:[kidValue:0, adultValue:1]]]
```

So on the receiving side there is code that does the following (simplified for this question):

```
map.each { key, value ->
    def adultValue = value.adultValue.toInteger()
}
```

But it obviously throws a NullPointer exception coz according to the receiving side there's no `map.adultValue`, there's only a `map.properties.adultValue`

So my question is, what can I do on the **sending** side so that the receiving side receives it the same way that it was sent? I'm not allowed to change the receiving side's code but I can look at the output.

For extra clarification, here's the code I use on the sending side to make the web service call:

```
def addAddons(map, anotherVar1, anotherVar2) {
    println(map)  // outputs the map as shown above
    try {
        def result
        def http = new HTTPBuilder("the real url, not shown here")
        http.request(Method.POST, groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON) { req ->
            body = [anotherVar1: anotherVar1, anotherVar2: anotherVar2, map: map]
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                result = json
            }
        }
        println("result: ${result}")
        return result
    } catch (all) {
        all.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I need to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also consider to use a JSON converter, so you still can create a Map and create the string out of the map.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def json = JsonOutput.toJson(map)
```

Comment: Your answer is so much better than mine, you get the vote xD

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking at it all wrong. I didn't realise but I was supposed to send a Json object instead of anything else which is why a map didn't work, and neither would an Arraylist (I tried that too, not shown in my question). So I tried to convert it to json using `groovy.json.JsonBuilder` but I couldn't figure that out so I ended up manually converting my map to json with the following code:

```
def json = '{'
def counter = 0
map.each { key, value ->
    if(counter == map.size()-1) {
        json += "\"$key\":{\"adultValue\":${value.adultValue},\"kidValue\":${value.kidValue}}"
    } else {
        json += "\"$key\":{\"adultValue\":${value.adultValue},\"kidValue\":${value.kidValue}},"
    }
        counter++
}
json += '}'
```

And that solved my problem